# Running Electrical cable through Loft/Attic

Tags: wiring, electrical

So we have had a car charger installed outside the garage, which is currently powered by standard twin and earth. is it ok to run an armoured cable from the meter, through the loft, (going up the toilet vent stack, and back down the other on the other side of the house, where there is another.), then underground into the garage and install a sub panel? (would save me taking up the patio...)

Comment: You say "from the meter" - are you planning on any fusing and isolation between the meter and the start of the new cable?

Comment: Do you mean through the actual toilet vent pipe of alongside it?

Comment: If it’s a car charger, wouldn’t you want it to be higher current than a ‘standard twin’? At any rate it would be best to consult a licensed electrician.

Comment: What country is this in? Does "from the meter" mean "from the main panel right next to the meter" or do you literally mean adding a connection right at the meter? What is the maximum capacity (Amps) of the charger?